# Is "qch. est à mourir" considered an anglicism calqued from "sth is to die for"? How commonly is it used?

Tags: expressions, anglicismes

> – J'aime tellement! L'ensemble est ravissant... Avec un gros coup de cœur pour les chaussures ;)
>
> – Merci ! Oui ces shoes sont **juste à mourir** ! Mais elles sont hyper fragiles...comme quoi même dans les années 70 certaines fabrications laissaient à désirer niveau qualité !

I assume the writer used the phrase "*juste à mourir*" with the idea "*simply to die for*" in mind.

In English, when you find something extremely good, attractive etc. you say informally:

- *Their green tea tiramisu is **simply to die for***.
- *She has blonde hair and hazel eyes **to die for***.

To express the idea of "*sth is to die for*", I usually go for "*à tomber*" instead of "*à mourir*" and say something like:

> Il a des jolis yeux bleus **à tomber** (**par terre**), un peu à la Leonardo DiCaprio.

The thing is that when I hear "*qch. est à mourir*", I can't help but associate it with "*qch. est **à mourir de rire***", "***à mdr***" in the sense of "*extrêmement drôle*".

Comment: Where is this from? Like you, I wouldn't say that, and “à mourir” makes me think of “à mourir de rire” first. But it could also be negative, e.g. in “à mourir d'ennui”.

Comment: @Gilles Refer to the first comment located far down below: http://tuttifruttivintage.blogspot.com/2015/10/zazou-du-dimanche.html  If those photos are anything to go by, there's nothing remotely ***drôle*** or ***barbant*** about the shoes she's wearing. Given that she goes on to point out a negative aspect of the product in the subsequent clause: "*Mais elles sont hyper fragiles*", the meaning of the preceding "*juste à mourir*" needs to be something complimentary by contrast. The other wording "*ravissant*", "*un gros coup de cœur*" also points towards the "*to die for*" interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne sais pas si c'est formellement considéré comme un calque de l'anglais mais c'en est un à l'évidence ici, et on a déjà un parler anglicisant avec l'emploi de *shoes* en anglais pour *chaussures*, le tout amplifié par le juste qui correspond à *simply (to die for)* comme on l'a remarqué.

Comme toi et d'autres j'associe « à mourir » à [*à mourir de rire*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_mourir_de_rire) signifiant *ridicule*, ou à l'exagération *à (en) mourir* (« Cela n'empêche pas, maman, que je m'embête à [mourir](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mourir). », Ponson du Terrail, au TLFi). Mais *juste* n'est pas accordé en nombre ici et donc ce n'est pas l'adjectif pour l'idée de *justesse*, quoiqu'il soit de toutes façons inhabituel il me semble d'avoir une hyperbole avec cette idée-là. Par ailleurs il y d'autres syntagmes ou dérivés usuels avec [*mourir*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mourir#D%C3%A9riv%C3%A9s) et une préposition.

J'en conclus qu'indépendamment de sa qualification, ce genre d'emploi est à contre-courant du système linguistique du français, engendre de la confusion en créant un trompe-l’œil et manque de précision. On peut facilement parler de [*chaussures de rêve*](https://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/to-die-for/618778?q=die%20for) voire dire hyperboliquement qu'elles sont *belles, magnifiques, exquises etc. à (en) mourir* etc. afin d'éviter le calque. Personnellement je suis habitué à des adjectifs expressifs comme « hallucinant(es) » pour marquer l'exagération ou le haut degré sans avoir recours à des expressions que je perçois comme étant affectées avec de simples objets.

Answer (score 2):

On entend depuis quelques années "une tuerie!", mais plutôt dans un contexte culinaire, plats, desserts etc.

Ce tiramisu au thé vert, une tuerie!

Answer (score 1):

The expression "**à mourir**" can be used to describe something boring. 
For example, you can say: "Cette conférence était à mourir d'ennui".

The fact is that the expressions "**à mourir**" and "**à tomber**" are extremely close, you can say: "**ces shoes sont juste à mourir**" or "**ces shoes sont juste à tomber**" relative to a positive attitude.