# Why the feminine "la" in "à la Leonardo DiCaprio", though he is a man?

Tags: grammaire, sens

I just saw this sentence I can't understand in other user's [thread](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/37078/is-qch-est-%C3%A0-mourir-considered-an-anglicism-calqued-from-sth-is-to-die-for).

"Il a des jolis yeux bleus à tomber par terre, **un peu à la Leonardo DiCaprio**."

What does this phrase mean, and why is the feminine "la" used, not the masculine "le", even though Leonardo DiCaprio is a man? At least, the last time I checked, he was. Does Michael Jackson have to be feminine, too, "à la Michael Jackson"?

Answer (score 10):

I would imagine *à la* is short for *à la manière de*.

Comment: Ou *à la façon de*.